# Build or modify the inspection tool on Chromium

Tags: html, web-scraping, webview, electron

I'm building a web scraping electron app for my work. Our it guys would approve a small portable app, but won't let me install node or run a web server so I have to use electron, in case anyone asks.

The goal is to collect details of our products from our vendors' sites. Then take those details and copy the into our inventory software site. Right now it's very time consuming. Well I could just manually do it, I don't really work in that department, and we have a ton of vendors. I want to make the scraper customizable by allowing the users to highlight the exact information on a vendor page, and either have the app automatically figure out what that is within the html or have a little pop up view of the html on the side so the users can select it, and create rule sets through a menu. I like the idea of the pop up because then you can visually see the element being selected as opposed to highlighting and hoping it gets what you want. If I do the pop up window though, I'd want to make it so when they double click on the element it will pop open the rule set maker and populate a field, and then give preselected options like "get content" or "get attribute" type of thing. That way it's a bit easier for people to grasp. And if I make it customizable, the employees can set them up on each vendor which saves me time, but also opens the ability for them to create a helper for more niche stuff that they may need because they constantly do things similar to this process. Finally, they could also use it on our inventory site and seller channels too, which would help even more employees out. And obviously my time would be freed up to get other projects done.

My problem, I'm not sure about how to go about making the pop up html view. Is there an api that lets me work with Chromium's built in one where I can customize it? I really like the feature of how it highlights the part of the page when you move over the html, and want that too, but like I said, I also need the opposite of highlighting on the page and then showing that section of html.

Can anyone share their thoughts on how to achieve this? Or if anyone has done something similar but in a different way, please share as well, maybe there's a better solution overall.

All I've managed so far was opening chromiums inspection tool automatically and using that to copy and paste into a little menu to create the rules, but I just think asking people to understand html like that makes it not as intuitive as I'd like. So really reducing how much html is shown would be great.